# stop autoscroll on overflow-x auto using angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have a socket event that uses  `$scope.items.unshift(item)` to the top of the list.

The html is using `<ol ng-repeat="item in items"><li>{{item.name}}</li></ol>`

The problem is that whenever an item comes in, if the user is scrolled down on the list at all

```
ol { overflow-y: auto; max-height: 100px; }
```

then the scroll position changes and if they are reading an item half way down, it jumps out of view or down a bit more on the page.

I'm trying to be able to add items to the list dynamically but not have the scrollbar move...such that the current scroll position is sticky even though items are flowing into the top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you add the height of an item from `scrollTop` as you unshift it. Get your list element `myList` and do something like:

```
var currentScrollTop = myList.scrollTop(),
itemHeight= 30;
$scope.items.unshift(item)
myList.scrollTop(currentScrollTop + itemHeight);
```

I did not test this code but it should give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks. i was thinking of doing a div that says "read x messages" and it only populates `$scope.items` when clicked.